# Desire2Learn - Home pages, Nav bars in use

Tags: navbar, desire2learn

Our "UI" is a bit cluttered and I'd like to inventory what home pages, nav bars, links and themes are used by what orgUnits in order to simplify and manage our UI.  In the Home Page Management Tool (and the others), there is a statement similar to "used in n orgUnits," so it seems as if that information is "somewhere."

Is there a way, either via a tool or via Valence to get a listing, by orgUnit of active Home Pages and Nav Bars, and I'm pushing it, but also what links and themes are being used by what other links (groups), Nav Bars etc?

thanks
cwt

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the Valence Learning Framework APIs do not offer a way to inspect or manage the collection of Home Pages or Nav Bars available to an org unit. Desire2Learn does provide a mechanism for registering client requests for the enhancement of the platform: you can ask for this feature through their [Product Ideas list](https://community.desire2learn.com/d2l/lp/navbars/1796/customlinks/external/15394) on their client Community site (if you're not yet a member, you can register for an account). Alternatively, you can make the request through your Account or Partner Manager and they can conduct the request through to the development teams responsible for this area of the product.